# Trying to get non ojbect. First(). Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
Page Controller
$Sport_Post = \App\Post::All()->Where('category_id','=',3)->first();
$Sport_Posts = \App\Post::All()->Where('category_id','=',3)->skip(1);
return view('welcome', compact('Sport_Post','Sport_Posts'));
Code of page
                                            @forelse($Sport_Post as $post)
        <div  id="content-number-1" class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 home-post1 content-number-1">
            <div class=""><img class="content-one-img content-img-chapter" src="{{$post->image}}"></div>
            <div class="content-text-img p-3"><p><a class="m-0 underImage aTagsHover" style="font-size: 20px" href="/inside/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a><br><span class="date-font"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{$post->created_at}}</span><span class="underBusiness"><br>{{$post->short_desc}}</span></p></div>
        </div>
        @empty
        <div  id="content-number-1" class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 home-post1 content-number-1">
            <div class="content-one-img content-img-chapter"></div>
            <div class="content-text-img p-3"><p><a class="m-0 underImage aTagsHover" style="font-size: 20px" href="#">No post</a><br><span class="date-font"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>No time</span><span class="underBusiness"><br>No post</span></p></div>
        </div>
        @endforelse
```

The error starts in src="{{$post->image}}">; What's wrong ? How to fix it

Comment: Trying to get property 'image' of non-object - the full error

Comment: can you dump $Sport_Post variable in the blade file and share the result?

Comment: No need to call `All()` this is enough `$Sport_Post = \App\Post::where('category_id','=',3)->first();` and here call the `get()` `$Sport_Posts = \App\Post::where('category_id','=',3)->skip(1)->get();`

Comment: Still this error without all

Comment: https://priscree.ru/img/0bdf28e9fcbbae.png . I don't know . I have 4 posts in my phpmyadmin.

Comment: $Sport_Post = \App\Post::Where('category_id','=',3)->first()->get();
This works but it's showing me all posts, not only first()

Comment: @Maksym because you are using `get()`, change to `$Sport_Post = \App\Post::Where('category_id','=',3)->first();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your code like below

in controller

```
$Sport_Post = \App\Post::Where('category_id','=',3)->first();
```

in blade file no need of for loop because $Sport_Post is a single object not a collection so modify blade code as below:

```
@if(isset($Sport_Post))
         <div  id="content-number-1" class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 home-post1 content-number-1">
            <div class=""><img class="content-one-img content-img-chapter" src="{{$Sport_Post->image}}"></div>
            <div class="content-text-img p-3"><p><a class="m-0 underImage aTagsHover" style="font-size: 20px" href="/inside/{{$Sport_Post->id}}">{{$Sport_Post->title}}</a><br><span class="date-font"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{$Sport_Post->created_at}}</span><span class="underBusiness"><br>{{$Sport_Post->short_desc}}</span></p></div>
        </div>
@else
        <div  id="content-number-1" class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 home-post1 content-number-1">
            <div class="content-one-img content-img-chapter"></div>
            <div class="content-text-img p-3"><p><a class="m-0 underImage aTagsHover" style="font-size: 20px" href="#">No post</a><br><span class="date-font"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>No time</span><span class="underBusiness"><br>No post</span></p></div>
        </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of All() change your code with following

```
$Sport_Post = \App\Post::Where('category_id','=',3)->first();
```

This query will fetch a single record from the database so you don't need `for each` loop.

now if you still getting the error `Trying to get property of non-object`
then convert the `$Sport_Post` variable to object or try to access the value as `array`